# Android emulator - Marshmallow - Sdcard is mounted writable but canWrite() is false and can't write files

Tags: android, bash, android-emulator, android-permissions, android-sdcard

tl;dr - I have an sdcard mounted as writable but canWrite() returns false and I can't save files which is the main point of my test script.

I have written a bash script which runs my automated tests on multiple emulator setups. I copy over the config.ini file into the same emulator and reboot it. This works fine.

In my test I take screenshots and try to save them to the emulator's sdcard. Sometimes it can and sometimes it can't but there is no consistency between which emulator can and can't save the images.

Also, I've managed to get some logging in place to determine various values which leads me to the main point of my question.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        int permissionStatus = context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (permissionStatus == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            System.err.println("**** permission allowed ****");
            System.err.println("**** state="+Environment.getExternalStorageState()+" ****");
            sleep(200);
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+filename+".png");
            System.err.println("**** fileState="+Environment.getExternalStorageState(file)+" ****");
            System.err.println("**** dir="+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+" ****");
            System.err.println("**** canwrite="+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite()+" ****");
            System.err.println("**** file = "+file+" ****");
            mDevice.takeScreenshot(file);
        } else {
            System.err.println("**** permission not allowed ****");
        }
    }
```

The logs I receive are as follows

```
07-18 01:29:10.975  3411  3426 W System.err: **** permission allowed ****
07-18 01:29:10.977  3411  3426 W System.err: **** state=mounted ****
07-18 01:29:11.179  3411  3426 W System.err: **** fileState=mounted ****
07-18 01:29:11.180  3411  3426 W System.err: **** dir=/storage/emulated/0 ****
07-18 01:29:11.181  3411  3426 W System.err: **** canwrite=false ****
07-18 01:29:11.181  3411  3426 W System.err: **** file = /storage/emulated/0/mainmenu.png ****
07-18 01:29:11.197  1307  1307 E EGL_emulation: tid 1307: eglCreateSyncKHR(1881): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
07-18 01:29:11.216  3411  3426 E UiAutomatorBridge: failed to save screen shot to file
07-18 01:29:11.216  3411  3426 E UiAutomatorBridge: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/mainmenu.png (Permission denied)
```

The problem as I see it is that the sdcard is mounted (and it is mounted as writable as if it was readonly then the value would be `mounted_ro`) but canWrite() is false on the externalStorageDirectory.

This is driving me insane! Does anyone have any ideas?

In each avd config file I have the lines 
`hw.sdCard=yes`
`sdcard.size=100M`

Answer (score 0):

Beginning in Android 6.0 or >7 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. [read about this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, but the permission has been allowed. If you look at these 3 lines

``if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        int permissionStatus = context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (permissionStatus == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {``

Then you will see that I am checking for permission to WRITE and it is accepted

Comment: but your logcat shows  /storage/emulated/0/mainmenu.png (Permission denied)

Comment: I know, that's what I'm asking. If the permission is supposedly granted by the app/system, based on the ``context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERN‌​AL_STORAGE);`` and then it isn't actually permitted, then what is the point of running ``checkSelfPermission``

Answer (score 0):

canWrite sometimes gives false for directories and its elements. its a bit erratic. can you try this

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    Log.d("Test", "sdcard mounted and writable");
}
else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    Log.d("Test", "sdcard mounted readonly");
}
else {
    Log.d("Test", "sdcard state: " + state);
}
```

Comment: The thing is, it seems to me that canWrite() is actually the most accurate. Because everytime canWrite() says false, I can't write. It seems to me the mounted status is wrong. Also, this test may tell me if the card is mounted, but what if it isn't? I want to have it mounted every time, not just find out if it is or not.

Comment: Ok I got your point. Also i see one small issue in the above code. The file path should be taken from Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() to access its location. I think .getAbsolutePath() part is missing is causing the issue

Comment: So no change in logs and canwrite response even after taking absolutepath

Comment: exactly 

07-18 11:35:42.894  3419  3436 W System.err: ***** permission allowed ******
07-18 11:35:42.896  3419  3436 W System.err:***** state=mounted ******
07-18 11:35:43.098  3419  3436 W System.err: ****************** fileState=mounted *****************
07-18 11:35:43.099  3419  3436 W System.err: ****************** dir=/storage/emulated/0 *****************
07-18 11:35:43.100  3419  3436 W System.err: ****************** canwrite=false *****************
07-18 11:35:43.100  3419  3436 W System.err: ****************** file = /storage/emulated/0/mainmenu.png *****************

Comment: Are you asking for this permission at manifest level or also in this activity as well before writing?

Comment: I am assuming the above part of your code is in onRequestPermissionsResult method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149472/discussion-between-russ-wheeler-and-kapsym).

Comment: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            String[] permissions = new String[] {" android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", " android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand("pm grant " + getTargetContext().getPackageName()+ permission);
            }
        }

Comment: I'm adding it in my automated test, as I can't get the 'user' to accept it as there is no user. This code works for some emulators and not others. So it's unlikely to be this line/section